# Reading Parquet file from Spark

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet, parquet-dataset

I use following method to read a **Parquet** file in Spark

```
scala> val df = spark.read.parquet("hdfs:/ORDER_INFO")
scala> df.show()
```

When I show content of DataFrame it displays with encoded language like below

```
[49 4E 53 5F 32 33]
[49 4E 53 5F 32 30]
```

In actual scenario these are Strings. Can anyone suggest a method to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Is your input file encoded? Have you tried this, if this works for you?

```
spark.read.option("encoding","UTF-8").parquet("hdfs:/ORDER_INFO")
```

Comment: I have tried it now but still the same result given. No its not encoded. I have used impala to read same table it gives the output correctly.

Comment: Sorry my mistake parquet file is encoded and also this issue is occur only for Strings not for integers, long and double values

Comment: Could you please tell me, Which encoding is being used to encode the parquet files?

Comment: Encoding is happened through impala. Using its default encode. Problem is I have no idea about that encode.

Comment: Got It. In that case you can use impala jdbc connector in Spark. It should solve the issue.

Comment: Impala JDBC connector in Spark is work fine with it. But the issue is we cannot use it. It makes a performance error in our system. Do you have any other known method?

Comment: Solved this issue. It is related to Impala and run below command before creation of table solve this issue.  `SET PARQUET_ANNOTATE_STRINGS_UTF8=1;`